# How do I get back to GUI?

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-4, gui, raspberry-pi-os

Recently my RPi started switching to a terminal on boot. I cannot get out of it and when i boot it says "Time Synchronization error" I've tried setting it manual, automatic and nothing has worked.

I also tried going into to `sudo raspi-config` and then switching it to GUI and it still does not go into GUI mode on boot.

[image: startx command]
[image: time error on boot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is impossible to say from the information provided. Most likely your filesystem is damaged or some file corrupted; restore from your backup. What happens if you run `startx`?

Comment: @Milliways I just updated it with pictures to show what happens.

Comment: DO NOT post illegible pictures of  text - post text. Did you run `startx`?

Comment: Yes, I cannot post text. The pictures provided should be more than clear and readable.